# Mapping native query result set to dto using Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a simple model defined using Gorm.

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string
    Password string
}

type Assistant struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID        int
    User          User
    InstitutionID int
}

type Professor struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID        int
    User          User
    InstitutionID int
}
```

I think that I have a query that is working and its function is to find an existing user with username passed from frontend. Query is working from the MySql workbench, but I cannot make it work from the program.

Here are my two attempts:

```
var users *[]model.User
db.Raw("SELECT u.id, u.username "+
    "FROM users u "+
    "LEFT JOIN assistants ass ON ass.user_id = u.id "+
    "LEFT JOIN professors prof ON prof.user_id = u.id "+
    "WHERE (u.username = @username1 AND ass.institution_id = @ins1)"+
    "      or                                           "+
    "      (u.username = @username2 AND prof.institution_id = @ins2)",
    map[string]interface{}{"username1": dto.Username, "ins1": dto.InstitutionID, "username2": dto.Username, "ins2": dto.InstitutionID},
).Find(&users)
```

and

```
var users *[]model.User
db.Raw("SELECT u.id, u.username "+
        "FROM users u "+
        "LEFT JOIN assistants ass ON ass.user_id = u.id "+
        "LEFT JOIN professors prof ON prof.user_id = u.id "+
        "WHERE ( u.username = ? AND ass.institution_id = ? )"+
        "      or                                           "+
        "      (u.username = ? AND prof.institution_id = ?) RETURNING id, username", dto.Username, dto.InstitutionID, dto.Username, dto.InstitutionID).Scan(&users)
```

Since I'm new to golang/gorm, error output is horrible. It is not giving me any hint of a problem (I'm coming from spring/java/hibernate), I do have some logging turned on.

I did visit the [docs](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html), but no luck.

This is the output in the console:

```
    goroutine 20 [running]:
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2122 +0x2f
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc000000480, {0xf09690, 0xc0001501c0}, 0xc000212000)
        C:/Users/Miljan.Puletic/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.8.0/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2122 +0x2f
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc000000480, {0xf09690, 0xc0001501c0}, 0xc000212000)
        C:/Users/User/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.8.0/mux.go:210 +0x1cf
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xf08698?}, {0xf09690, 0xc0001501c0}, 0xc000212000)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2936 +0x316
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000408ab0, {0xf09bf8, 0xc000422030})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x612
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/net/http/server.go:3089 +0x5ed
```

Comment: "error output is horrible" - Can you include it? It might not be for those you're asking to help you.

Comment: Is that really all the output you're getting? There should be an error before that stack trace. If that's it, you need to include more code to give more context.

Comment: yeah that is all the output. Bug was in some other part of the program, flow control was invoking some other function, this one is working. I apologize, false alarm. Happens in 3am.